# How to connect gRPC server with bearer token using client.connect() method? in k6

Tags: grpc, bearer-token, k6

while connecting to the gRPC server I was not able to pass the bearer token

I tried to pass it as a key-value pair in an object {authorization: bearer "token"} but an error occurred "no param authorization exists", I want to use server reflection directly from grpc server in k6...

this is the line of code I am using for connecting the hosted grpc server
but i need to pass the bearer token to access the server reflection
"client.connect(__ENV.server_url,{reflect: true});"

Comment: Your question would benefit from more detail including of the call you're making and the error you received. I'm unfamiliar with [k6](https://k6.io) but I assume you're using [`Client.connect`](https://k6.io/docs/javascript-api/k6-net-grpc/client/client-connect/) which doesn't permit providing metadata which you probably need to invoke your method(s). Try using `Client.connect` and **then** [`Client.invoke`](https://k6.io/docs/javascript-api/k6-net-grpc/client/client-invoke/), this supports [`gRPC.params`](https://k6.io/docs/javascript-api/k6-net-grpc/params/) including metadata.

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [ask], and then [edit] your question to provide a [mre] as _text_ (not screenshots or external link).